# How can I store a UserID and Name with the LoginControl?

Tags: asp.net, database, session, authentication

I have a LoginControl that works great, however, I want it to store more information than just being authenticated or not. I would like to store the UserID of the user so when they make changes I can call that UserID and record that they made the changes.

Here is my code.

```
 Dim db As New DataClassesDataContext

        Dim User = (From UserTable In db.Users _
                    Select UserTable _
                    Where UserTable.Active = True And _
                    UserTable.Name = LoginControl.UserName And _
                    UserTable.Password = RC.CryptedText _
                    )
        If User.Count = 1 Then
            e.Authenticated = True
        Else
            e.Authenticated = False
        End If
```

I just want to be able to call the UserID later, I'm able to login and access the pages fine, but something like

```
 Session("UserID") = LoginControl.UserName
```

Would be great as long as the session doesnt get cleared.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this May be this will help you.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/syedshakeer/1789/
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020220.htm
http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/asp.net-2.0/forms-authentication-in-asp.net-2.0.html

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you use the built-in [Membership and Role Manager APIs](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/security/membership.aspx) for anything related to security and user management. It's quite easy to extend the model, and add addtional properties to your user objects with [Profiles](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/profile/default.aspx).

Comment: "Quite easy to extend"? You'd be the first person i know to think so. :)

Comment: Thanks. :) I guess I meant adding user specific data is pretty easy with the Membership/Profiles providers. I even rolled my own implementation of the Roles provider at some point, that really was pretty simple.